# VS2015 ASP.NET MVC Core new project template for full .NET missing

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to create a new .NET Core ASP.NET MVC application running on the full .NET Framework but the only Visual Studio template I have is for the cross-plat .NET Core.

I know you can do this, I've seen screenshots, here's one:

[image: Screen shot from VS 2015]

But for me, I only have (.NET Core) as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select Web in the left column of the new project dialogue in Visual Studio 2015, because I don't know why.

[image: Screen shot from VS 2015]